# Number of items in cart empty in only one vocab, for anonymous users

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I use this code below to show the total number of items in the commerce cart block:

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {

      if ($block->module === 'commerce_cart') {
        global $user;
        if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
          // Count the number of product line items on the order.
          $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
          $quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
          if($quantity > 0){
            $data['content'] = ('<a class="varukorg" href="/cart">Varukorg ('.$quantity.')</a>');
          }else{
            $data['content'] = ('<span class="cart-empty-block">Varukorg (0)</span>');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So if the total number of items is for ex. 3 I have a link that says

> Varukorg (3)

This works perfectly when logged in, and for the most part also for anonymous users. But when an anonymous user tries to look at products in a certain category (a taxonomy view), the $quantity variable gets the value zero. And the text shown is:

> Varukorg (0)

I have 7 vocabularies with quite a few terms, that I use to show products of different kinds. So why does my code above work for most of the vocabs, but not for all? I have read the post about "Disable SQL rewriting" (https://www.drupal.org/node/1269054#comment-6380586), but in my case this did not help.

I can just type /cart after the web root, which opens the cart with the correct content. It's just the `$quantity` variable above that gets the wrong value when an anonymous user is looking at certain taxonomy views, but not others.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: Apparently, in the taxonomy pages where I cannot get the total number of items in the cart, the global $user variable does not work... I put this as the first lines in the function:

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  global $user;
  drupal_set_message(t('User %uid',
    array('%uid' => $user->uid)));
```

And I get no message on the pages where I get the zero value. But on all the pages where the total number works, the message is shown. So why have I no access to the global $user, on just a few taxonomy pages, when not logged in?

UPDATE 2: I am an idiot... the problem was that some pages got cached by Boost the first time they were visited and of course, after that, they would still show that same page... Please close this question and sorry about the noise.

Comment: `the global $user variable does not work` That makes no sense... Drupal defines that for every page. Could it be you have overwritten in some other piece of custom code?

Comment: Neograp734: Or maybe that hook does not get called on every page... I am not sure how to find the cause of this problem.